# Can someone tell me what crashed OBS?

Tags: applications

```
Process:               obs [1401]
Path:                  /Applications/OBS.app/Contents/MacOS/obs
Identifier:            com.obsproject.obs-studio
Version:               24.0.6 (24.0.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           obs [1401]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2020-04-08 06:07:09.422 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G22010)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        B5E03C66-3711-721B-EEA9-0F54F7D4128A


Time Awake Since Boot: 1600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    Kernel Alloc Once      000000000582a000-000000000582b000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   com.allocinit.camtwist.dal      0x000000000f52aa05 -[comallocinitCMIOCTBridge init] + 87
2   com.allocinit.camtwist.dal      0x000000000f52a9a0 +[comallocinitCMIOCTBridge instance] + 54
3   com.allocinit.camtwist.dal      0x000000000f52a63a -[CTCMPluginRGBStream initWithPlugin:andDeviceId:] + 89
4   com.allocinit.camtwist.dal      0x000000000f52cdef -[CTCMPluginDevice initialize] + 199
5   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8cafab98 CMIO::DAL::PlugInManagement::CreatePlugIn(CMIO::DAL::CFPlugIn const*) + 806
6   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8caf905e CMIO::DAL::PlugInManagement::CreateOrLazyLoadPlugIns(std::__1::vector<CMIO::DAL::CFPlugIn*, std::__1::allocator<CMIO::DAL::CFPlugIn*> >*, std::__1::vector<CMIO::DAL::PlugIn*, std::__1::allocator<CMIO::DAL::PlugIn*> >*, std::__1::vector<CMIO::DAL::PlugInManagement::MatchingInfo*, std::__1::allocator<CMIO::DAL::PlugInManagement::MatchingInfo*> >*, void (*)(void*, unsigned int)) + 84
7   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8caf8cd5 CMIO::DAL::PlugInManagement::Initialize() + 441
8   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8cafc86d CMIO::DAL::System::InitializeDevices() + 9
9   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8cafcae2 CMIO::DAL::System::CheckOutInstance() + 398
10  com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff8cb229b2 CMIOObjectSetPropertyData + 269
11  mac-avcapture.so                0x000000000f5124b3 obs_module_load + 67
12  libobs.0.dylib                  0x00000001080874f3 obs_init_module + 83
13  libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108088380 load_all_callback + 64
14  libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108088299 obs_find_modules + 2153
15  libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108087a13 obs_load_all_modules + 35
16  com.obsproject.obs-studio       0x0000000105863a87 OBSBasic::OBSInit() + 775
17  com.obsproject.obs-studio       0x0000000105843aab OBSApp::OBSInit() + 491
18  com.obsproject.obs-studio       0x0000000105846549 main + 5209
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8773e5ad start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f4efa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bdb8165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bdb7dcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f45e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91613578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f3db6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91614728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108045949 os_event_timedwait + 169
3   libobs.0.dylib                  0x000000010807c47c obs_hotkey_thread + 396
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161399d _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161391a _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611351 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: audio-io: audio thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f410a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92906d0f nanosleep + 199
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92906c02 usleep + 54
3   libobs.0.dylib                  0x000000010803191c audio_thread + 460
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161399d _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161391a _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611351 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: video-io: video thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991edfae semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108045ad0 os_sem_wait + 16
2   libobs.0.dylib                  0x000000010803001f video_thread + 79
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161399d _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161391a _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611351 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: libobs: graphics thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991f410a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92906d0f nanosleep + 199
2   libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108045d8d os_sleepto_ns + 93
3   libobs.0.dylib                  0x000000010809491d obs_graphics_thread + 5261
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161399d _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161391a _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611351 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff991edfae semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libobs.0.dylib                  0x0000000108045ad0 os_sem_wait + 16
2   libobs-scripting.dylib          0x000000000f088ae9 defer_thread + 25
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161399d _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9161391a _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91611351 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007ff87c9d0c78  rbx: 0x00007ff87c9d0ab0  rcx: 0x0000000000000003  rdx: 0x0000000006001c80
  rdi: 0x00007ff87c9d0b60  rsi: 0x0000000000001000  rbp: 0x00007fff5a3e45a0  rsp: 0x00007fff5a3e4568
   r8: 0x0000000006001d40   r9: 0x0000000006000000  r10: 0x00000000ffffffff  r11: 0xfffffff9225ec7fa
  r12: 0x00007fff88c034c0  r13: 0x00007fff88c034c0  r14: 0x00007fff88c034c0  r15: 0x00007ff87c9cf850
  rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000014
Trap Number:     14
```

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the macOS part of https://obsproject.com/download, you'll see that

> the macOS release of OBS Studio supports macOS 10.12 and newer.

Comment: I've downloaded an older version of OBS that does support 10.11.6 but still crashes as soon as I open it. It gives me the same report as the newer OBS when it crashes.

Comment: @HarponyFoss Did you check the OBS version number in the crash report to make sure you got the right version? Besides that it might be better to use the OBS support channels because you might not be the only one with the problem and they should be able to help you faster.